# Class of transitive $M$ which model $ZFC$

Tags: set-theory

Consider the following class:

{$x: $"$ x $ is transitive$ $"$ \wedge x\models ZFC$}$:=A$. 
If this class is non-empty then it has a $\in$-minimal element. Is this correct?

My argument used the fact that non-emptiness of $A$ implies there is an $M$ which models the axioms of foundation and comprehension. And using absoluteness results (since $M$ is transitive) I was able (I think) to show that this class must have a $\in$-minimal element.

Sketch: take any $M\in A$. 
If $M$ is not $\in$-minimal in $A$ then there is $N \in M$ s.t. $N\in A$. If $N$ is not $\in$-minimal in $A$, then consider {$x\in N:x\in A$}, which is a non-empty set in $M$ (it is a set in $M$ since $M$ models comprehension). And since $M$ also models foundation, then {$x\in N:x\in A$} has a $\in$-minimal element which must also be a $\in$-minimal element of $A$.

Is this correct?

Any help is appreciated
-Thanks

Comment: If the universe satisfies $\sf ZF$ then every non-empty class has an $\in$-minimal element. Regardless to whether or not the elements of the class are transitive, or models of $\sf ZFC$ themselves.

Comment: Anyway, what is interesting about this class is that it contains a $\subset$-minimal element, which is the unique model of the form $L_\alpha$ in $A$ with no $L_\beta$ in $A$ for $\beta<\alpha$. (This $\alpha$ is countable, of course.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working in $ZFC$, the axiom of foundation implies that every nonempty class has a $\in$-minimal element. (See $\textit{Set Theory}$ by Jech page 64.) Hence this immediately implies that if your class above is nonempty, it has a $\in$-minimal element.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that foundation says that every non-empty set has a $\in$-minimal element. ie that $\in$ is well-founded on the universe $V$.

Comment: @user52534 It is not trivial to show that this implies every nonempty class has a $\in$-minimal element. The idea is: since the class (denoted by) $C$ is nonempty. Take $L \in C$. If $L \cap C$ is nonempty, you have found your minimal element. If not, let $T(L)$ be the transitive closure of $L$. Let $X = T(L) \cap C$ which is nonempty set. Foundation gives a minimal element for $X$. You can show this is a minimal element of $C$. Look in Jech for a more complete exposition on Foundation.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this fact. I just assumed it wasn't true since in Kunen, he gives a proof that $\in$ is well-founded on  $ON$ (the class of ordinals). I haven't come across the generalization to any class in his book yet.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a class $C$ which is inhabited by $x$. Let $\alpha$ be the rank of $x$. Then $C \cap V_{\alpha + 1}$ is a *set* containing $x$ and so has a $\in$-minimal element, which must also be $\in$-minimal for $C$, since the only elements we threw away had greater rank.

Comment: I'm not 100% confident in this argument especially in light of the comments on the other answer, but I can't see a flaw in it.

Comment: Your proof is essentially the same. I used the transitive closure of $x$. But if $x$ has rank $\alpha$, then the transitive closure of $x$ is a subset of $V_{\alpha + 1}$. The proof is completed in the same way.